# Limits of Integration in finding Volume

Tags: integration

Let R be a solid inside $x^2+y^2=9$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2=25$ then find $\int \int \int z dV$

What are the limits of integration in Rectangular, Cylindrical and Spherical cases?

I am confused as the integral evaluates to zero.

I have tried the following limits.

Rectangular : $0 \leq x \leq 3$, $0 \leq y \leq \sqrt{9-x^2}$, $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$

Polar: $-\sqrt{25-r^2} \leq z \leq \sqrt{25-r^2}$, $0 \leq r \leq 3$, $0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$

Spherical: $0 \leq \phi \leq  \frac{\pi}{2}$, $0 \leq r \leq 3$, $0 \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Are the limits correct. Please advise where I am going wrong.

Comment: Rectangular coordinates are wrong: you have forgotten about negative roots. $-3\le x\le 3,-\sqrt{9-x^2}\le y\le\sqrt{9-x^2},-\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}\le z\le\sqrt{25-x^2-y^2}$ are the correct limits since you are integrating over the entire circle. Note that the polar coordinates are correct and you have correctly varied $z$ from $-\sqrt{25-r^2}\to\sqrt{25-r^2}$. The spherical coordinates are also wrong but given your order of integration the limits will be a little difficult to compute.

Comment: @ShubhamJohri, If we use these limits, say rectangular and polar, the integral evaluates to zero. Is that okay?

Comment: The answer is $0$...you can see that the region is symmetric with respect to $xy$ plane and the integrand $z$ is positive above the $xy$ plane and negative below it.